# Android Logging in C++

Tags: android, android-ndk

I understand that i can use

```
__android_log_write
```

which take in char array.

But how can i log the following V8 types :

```
v8::Local<v8::Context>

v8::Local<v8::Value>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect as the output? `v8::Value` has a `ToString` method which gives you a `v8::String`, which I'm guessing you can get a regular `char*` out of somehow.

Comment: @Michael Tried that got an error class V8::Context has no member ToString.